# One Set of POCO classes with interchangeable databases

Tags: .net, orm, subsonic, subsonic3, data-access-layer

I have an application that uses a set of tables to store data.

Based on client requirements they can use either Oracle or SQL Server.

Is there a way I can create all the POCO classes that represent the tables and then somehow when the Save() method is called it updates the correct database?

So for example:

```
Person p = new Person;
p.Name = "John";
p.Save(); //This saves it to the database but somehow it knows to use a Oracle connection or SQL Connection
```

**UPDATE:** I have just read that the Entity Framework 4 supports multiple databases but previous versions there was a lot of bloat with it so I'm a bit put off by it and not sure whether this would provide me what I want.

Comment: `somehow it knows to use a Oracle connection or SQL Connection` 
That would be because the connection string was either to Oracle, or SQL Server. It's not magic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have this kind of requirement I will use some ORM which works with POCOs (preferably using Repository Pattern like [Subsonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com)). Then you can just change connection in configuration file or use IOC to init the ORM with correct context.

Comment: Will Subsonic create the POCO's based on one database and you can then specify different connections in the config file?

Comment: Yes @Jon if the table structure and datatypes (on db side) are in aggrement then it will not be a problem. You can use two `SimpleRepository` objects with different connection strings.

Comment: Reading the Subsonic docs and it seems that using SimpleRepository it wont create the POCO's.

Comment: try `var repo=new SimpleRepository("connection string");` now you can create poco from db using this: `var poco = repo.Find<POCO_CLASS>(x=>x.Name == "some name to match");` But yes you have to code the classes first for each table in db (the table name must be plural like for User class you should have Users table)

Comment: Thanks.  I think what I will do is use the Active Record T4 templates to generate my POCO's then use the Repository pattern and therefore I can just switch the connection string. Thanks.

Comment: Only issue I have just realised is that the DB I am using is an inherited one not new so the table names are not plural and I wont be able to change them. Can I still use Subsonic?

Comment: can't comment. try getting latest version from git and try or you can ask Rob Conry, he will be helpful.